# When should I use "when" and "while"?

Tags: prepositions

> But you can't find anything ***while*** you're crying.
>   But you can't find anything ***when*** you're crying.
>   I'll tell you about it ***while*** Frank saddles the horse.
>   I'll tell you about it ***when*** Frank saddles the horse.

When should I use *when*, and when *while*?
Are these sentences correct?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When used to mean "during the time that something is happening," *while* is synonym of *when*.

> While I was waiting at the bus stop, three buses went by in the opposite direction.

All the sentences you wrote are correct.

Comment: "Correct" is not the same thing as "synonymous". See Hellion's answer: while the first pair of examples is pretty much equivalent, the second pair definitely isn't.

Comment: We often use when before the past simple and while before the past continuous.

Answer (score 17):

The main difference between these two words is that *when* usually means *at* or *immediately after some **specific point** in time*, whereas *while* always means *during some [usually, **extended**] **period** of time*.

Thus, for example, if we take an activity often considered so quick it happens at a "*point* in time"...

> You should cover your mouth **when** sneezing. *([3460 hits in Google Books](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22mouth%20while%20sneezing%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22mouth%20when%20sneezing%22&oq=%22mouth%20when%20sneezing%22&gs_l=serp.3...3920.5398.0.5998.5.5.0.0.0.0.121.320.4j1.5.0...0.0...1c.1.8.psy-ab.lhzqNBui4r0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45107431,d.d2k&fp=3ba4c81d278ccaf7&biw=1396&bih=872))*
>    You should cover your mouth **while** sneezing. *([131 hits](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22mouth%20while%20sneezing%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22mouth%20while%20sneezing%22&oq=%22mouth%20while%20sneezing%22&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.1.198532.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c..8.psy-ab.Z-Z4hwCiuWE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45107431,d.d2k&fp=3ba4c81d278ccaf7&biw=1396&bih=872))*

...but if we take an activity that lasts [a lot!] longer...

> You should not smoke **while** pregnant. *([2940 hits](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22smoke%20when%20pregnant%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22smoke%20while%20pregnant%22&oq=%22smoke%20while%20pregnant%22&gs_l=serp.3...19315.20583.0.21449.5.5.0.0.0.0.96.313.5.5.0...0.0...1c.1.8.psy-ab.rXMAPEdIJx4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45107431,d.d2k&fp=3ba4c81d278ccaf7&biw=1396&bih=872))*
>    You should not smoke **when** pregnant. *([137 hits](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22smoke%20when%20pregnant%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22smoke%20when%20pregnant%22&oq=%22smoke%20when%20pregnant%22&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.1.6063917.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c..8.psy-ab.UqxMz6zyxzg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45107431,d.d2k&fp=3ba4c81d278ccaf7&biw=1396&bih=872))*

...the *when/while* preference reverses. Without more context (how long/how often do you cry?), there's nothing to choose between OP's first two examples. *While* would be more likely if you're crying right now, but either would probably be accepted in most contexts.

---

Also note that in...

> He opened the door **when** I knocked
>    He opened the door **while** I knocked

...the *when* version means *immediately after* (a perfectly normal situation). The *while* version forces you to imagine some unlikely contrived context where the knocking and the opening are taking place *at the same time*. Thus in OP's second pair of examples...

> 1: *while* always means *I'll tell you **at the same time as** Frank saddles the horse*
>    2: *when* strongly implies *I won't tell you **until [after]** Frank starts/finishes saddling the horse*

...where in #2 only the specific context distinguishes whether the intention is to start telling at the same time as Frank starts saddling, or [immediately] after he's finished.

---

Finally, note that *when* can often be paraphrased as *on any of various occasions when*, whereas *while* may be used to mean *during the one and only timespan when something is happening*.

Answer (score 3):

In the context that you gave, *While* means "during the time that something is happening";
*When* means "at the time that something happens".

In the first pair of sentences, because the action of "crying" is generally understood to last for some time, the distinction is minimal; the words can be used interchangeably.

In the second pair of sentences, there is a difference in meaning.  Using *while* focuses on the actual time spent doing the saddling, and using *when* focuses on the point at which the saddling action starts.  Therefore, if you use *while*, my understanding is that the saddling has already started, you are going to tell me something right now, and you will be able to tell me most or all of it before the saddling is complete.  If you use *When*, my understanding is that the saddling will begin at some point in the future, and that point is the point at which you will tell me something.

Comment: Yes, but depending on *precise* context, "when" in the second pair might specifically mean you don't intend to say anything until ***after*** the horse ***has been saddled***. And it's an unmerited assumption that "while" would only be used *when saddling has already started*.

Answer (score 0):

*X when Y* or *when Y, X* means that if Y happens, X happens.  Y will be the start of something or an event that doesn't have a duration.

*X while Y* or *while Y, X* means that for the duration of Y happening, X happens.  Y will be a continuous activity or something that has a duration.