# when and while participle clauses

Tags: grammar

> *While* swimming yesterday, I saw a dolphin.
>
> *When* swimming yesterday, I saw a dolphin.

Are both correct? The course book I have treats them the same.

But for me 'when' is more for habitual actions.

> *When* walking home late at night, be careful.

Or is there no difference? Thanks!

Comment: _When_ is perfectly acceptable in this context. _When [I was] swimming yesterday..._ The other usage would be understood as _when [you are] walking home..._

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use "when" and "while"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/when-should-i-use-when-and-while) See also [The difference between "as" "when" and "while"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83971/) and [As, when or while?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69514/as-when-or-while), among others.

Comment: Semantically, there's no practical difference between "when" and "while" here. The former means "on the occasion when I was swimming yesterday", while the latter means "during the time while I was swimming yesterday". Each entails the other.

Answer (score 3):

"When" can simply mean at the time that something happened. So it is basically equivalent to "while" in the swimming examples. ("While" emphasizes that the activity lasts a period of time.)

> When walking home late at night, be careful.

Yes, since there is no specific situation/time referenced here, this would normally receive a habitual reading (such that "when" can be paraphrased as "whenever"). Though perhaps less common, a "while" clause can receive a habitual interpretation as well:

- While conducting a job interview, it is important to convey a positive attitude.

For me, using "while" rather than "when" here focuses more on the stretch of time that the interview occupies. But either is acceptable.

Comment: An example where they are NOT interchangeable: _**When/\*while** you fall and injure yourself, seek treatment immediately._ Seeking treatment is not happening during the time span of falling, it is soon after. *When* works because it is the same general period of time; *while* does not work because it is not the same specific span of time.

Comment: That same "simultaneous / immediately after" distinction applies to [my own examples](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/5290/126) *He opened the door **when** I knocked* and *He opened the door **while** I knocked*.

Comment: Ok, it's clear now. Thanks for the answers!